# Libre Calc: count duplicate values

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I have some values in one column (A) like this:

```
 1. 5201890000018
 2. 5201890000018
 3. 5201890000018
 4. 5010175810538
 5. 5010175810538
 6. 5010175810538
 7. 5010175810538
 8. 50008667
 9. 50008667
```

Is there a formula to count the duplicate values and put the result in columns B and C like this:

```
5201890000018   3

5010175810538   4

50008667        2
```

***EDIT:***
I found a solution. I remove duplicates and i put the results in column b and then i check with countif in column c how many times the values in column b appear in column a. I am still trying to find a more auto way, maybe with a macro or something.

Answer (score 7):

You might consider a pivot table (Insert menu) more automated. Select your numbers, Insert, drag the `Available Fields:` entry to `Row Fields:` and to `Data Fields:`, double-click on the latter to select Count and then move the result to B1 of your source data sheet.